# How to add UIColor objects into NSMutableArray in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, uicolor

When I add `UIColor` objects into array i got `Thread1: Program received signal: “SIGBRT”` this error.

```
 NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        UIColor *color1,*color2, *color3,*color4;
        color1 = [UIColor blueColor];
        color2 = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.5 
                            saturation:0.1 
                            brightness:0.2
                                 alpha:1.0];
        color3 = color2;
        [array addObject:color1];//No Problem
        [array addObject:color2];//No Problem
        [array addObject:color3];//No Problem
        [array addObject:color4];//Problem is here.....
```

When I add first three objects into array there is no problem. But when i add last object i get error. What is the problem in this code? Should i assign any thing to fourth object(color4) like first three objects? Is it necessary? Why?...

Please suggest me with example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

color4 is not initialized and you try to insert nil in your array. Initialize color4 like the other colors.

Answer (score 6):

Until you don't initialize your pointer (color4), it points to an undefined location, at which there's possibly no object, just garbage. Maybe it's not even a valid menory location. When dereferencing that, it will crash narurally. You need to initialize it to a valid object.

Furthermore, that object cannot be `nil` or else NSMutableArray itself will throw an exception.

Comment: +1 Sometimes the color4 might have nil, but it depends. As H2CO3 said, if it is nil, the NSMutableArray will throw an exception.

Comment: I feel that the problem is because the object is nil, not because it is a garbage.

Comment: @EmptyStack you may be right. OP haven't posted whether or not he gets an NSException thrown. Signals such as SIGABRT (SIGSEGV, etc.) tend to be sent to a process upon memory corruption.

Comment: `[array addObject:color4]` will invoke [color4 retain], if it is nil, calling retain is OK, but as @danielbeard said, there will be an exception. But calling retain on an invalid object like garbage will raise the "SIGBRT".

Comment: @H2CO3 Actually he does in the first line (SIGBRT).  That means this is actually the correct answer, and not the accepted one.

Comment: @borrrden I know :) The problem is, both the OP and the author of the accepted answer think that uninitialized pointer == nil pointer, but this is not true.

Comment: Actually, under ARC stack variables are initialised to nil. Under the transitioning to ARC notes from the developer.apple.com page - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW5

Answer (score 2):

Color4 is nil when you add it to the array. NSMutableArrays are nil terminated. This means that the last element in an NSMutableArray is nil. You can't manually add nil objects to an array, this means that data after the nil object would be ignored!

The following code produces an exception:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIColor *color;

[array addObject:color];
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

The solution is to initialise the color4 variable before adding it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 UIColor* color1 = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIColor* color2 = [UIColor greenColor];
    UIColor* color3 = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIColor* color4 = [[UIColor alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray* arrayColor = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:color1, color2, nil ];

    [arrayColor addObject:color3];
    [arrayColor addObject:color4];
```

Comment: definitely not the 2nd one...you can't insert `nil` into an array.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create first UIColor object and add in array like this

```
  NSArray *mycolorsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:color1, color2, nil];
```